# Bash command output as numeric variable

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, scripting

I do this:

```
VAL=$(wc -l < file_with_5_lines)
for i in {1..${VAL}}; do echo $i; done
```

Expecting this result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Instead of that I get this one:

```
{1..5}
```

> EDIT

This question was marked as duplicate but the accepted answer for the other question isn't valid in my opinion. The proposed solution is this:

```
VAL=$(wc -l < file_with_5_lines)

for i in {1..$((VAL))}; do
        echo $i
done
```

And continues to give me this result:

```
{1..5}
```

Instead of:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Just write a normal numeric `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brace expansion is done before parameter expansion and that's why we can't have a variable inside `{...}` construct.  Use a regular for loop so that you don't depend on an external command like `seq`:

```
for ((i = 1; i <= VAL; i++)); do
    # your code here
done
```

Comment: This is the best solution, without external commands

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code,

```
VAL=$(wc -l < file_with_5_lines)
for i in `seq ${VAL}`
do 
  echo $i
done
```

Comment: This works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
VAL=$(wc -l < file_with_5_lines)
for i in $(seq $VAL);do echo $i;done
```

Comment: what's wrong here?

Comment: Try here: https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online 
`echo -e "line1\nline2\nline3\nline4\nline5" > input.txt;VAL=$(wc -l < input.txt);for i in $(seq $VAL);do echo $i;done`

Comment: This works fine